# Detecting first non silent sample index

Tags: puredata

I have an audio file that I read with [tabread~]). The audio starts with some silence and I am trying to find the first non silent sample index.

I have tried to use [bonk~], [fiddle~] or [sigmund~] but the results were approximate and not constants.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks.

Pascal

[image]

Comment: Note that silence isn't necessarily zero - just very very low.

Comment: Absolutely. I have been suggested a simple solution. I just read the array until I find a value above or below a very low value. Simple ;^) So far it is working.

Comment: You can answer the question yourself if you have an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528113/detecting-first-non-silent-sample-index/38535094?noredirect=1#comment64561899_38535094